# Static page to dynamic wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, static

I found few questions related to this, but I'm totally new to WordPress and even some basic things are hard to understand, so I humbly ask not to close this topic immediately :)

I created my one-page website, put it on **htmlblank5** theme and now trying to work my way on localhost WP. It seems all is working.

I don't understand the concept of making it dynamic in one page (though I understand the idea of how blog's work with pages and posts). So the question is how in general should I approach this "problem" and where to start.

Here are a few lines of my code:

1. expanding bootstrap buttons with a simple list and paragraph inside.

```
    <div class="container">
      <h2 id="Paslaugos" class="d-flex justify-content-center">xxxxxxxx</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-xm-12">
    <p>
      <a class="btn mygtukai" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">xxxxxxxxx</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xm-12">
      <button class="btn mygtukai" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">xxxxxxxxxxx</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xm-12">

      <button class="btn mygtukai" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample3">xxxxxxx</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-xm-12">
        <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-center">xxxxxxxxxxxx</h4>
            <ul class="kinas-teatras">
              <li>xxxxxxx</li>
              <li>xxxxxxxxx</li>
              <li>xxxxxxxxx</li>
              <li>xxxxxxxxxxx</li>
              <li>xxxxxxxxxx</li>
              <li>xxxxxxxxxxx</li>
            </ul>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

2. Bootstrap cards about the projects done(some kind of portfolio)

```
    <div class="container">
    <h2 id="Darbai" class="d-flex justify-content-center">xxxxxxxx</h2>
    <div class="card-columns">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="img/hotel4.jpg" alt="Card image cap" title="Kalbėk">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-center"><b>xxxxxxxxxx</b></h4>
          <h5 class="d-flex justify-content-center darbaib"><b>xxxxxxxxxxx</b></h5>
          <p class="card-text">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
          <p class="darbaip card-text">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

These are just examples of what I'm working with. If needed I can post all HTML.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you have to install a fresh wordpress site:
   https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/
2. Then, put your html code on themes/Twenty Nineteen/index.php inside 
   *Twenty Nineteen is the theme for default actually.
3. Thats all, you will see your website.
4. You need to learn wordpress to change the static data to dynamic
   data, I recommend you learn about ACF Plugin and visit the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page

good luck!